# Foundation - 'Show Desktop Site' option

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am building out a site using the Foundation framework (http://foundation.zurb.com/). I want to offer users a "Show Full Desktop Site" link on the site that allows the desktop/large version of the site to be loaded even on small devices.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Why are you needing this? The responsive nature of your site should allow your content to display in the best format for your device. Do you have content that you are hiding for smaller screens?

Comment: It was more a request that was made, because I agree with your point. But yes, let's say I am hiding certain content for "small"/mobile screens that I wish to allow someone, should they be so interested, to see even if they are on a small device.

Answer (score 0):

This site offers one solution: http://css-tricks.com/user-opt-out-responsive-design/

A quick summary: you can prefix your responsive styles with a .resp class, and then add the .resp class to your body tag based on whether or not a query string parameter is present.